# what does "typedef see below" mean in c++ standard library source code?

Tags: c++, llvm, unique-ptr

When I am reading the source code of standard library, I always see usage of "see below" For example, in the source code of libcxx memory: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/memory, in the unique_ptr definition, a piece of code with "typedef see below pointer" the code looks like this:

```
typedef see below pointer;
typedef T element_type;
typedef D deleter_type;

// constructors
constexpr unique_ptr() noexcept;
explicit unique_ptr(pointer p) noexcept;
unique_ptr(pointer p, see below d1) noexcept;
unique_ptr(pointer p, see below d2) noexcept;
unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& u) noexcept;
unique_ptr(nullptr_t) noexcept : unique_ptr() { }
template <class U, class E>
    unique_ptr(unique_ptr<U, E>&& u) noexcept;
template <class U>
    unique_ptr(auto_ptr<U>&& u) noexcept;
...
```

I want to know what does this mean, and how it works? thanks!

Comment: Well, did you see what's below?

Comment: That's not valid source code. It's part of the **specification** for `std::unique_ptr`, which is **text**, not compilable code.

Answer (score 3):

That's part of a comment. View the file with syntax highlighting next time.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some kind of contrivance like

```
#define see const; /*you are allowed to define something to a keyword*/
struct below{};
typedef see below pointer;/*this will now compile*/
```

`typedef see below pointer;` is not syntactically valid. It's part of the documentation in the source code that you cite.